# Can you multiclass a land druid with a moon druid?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, multi-classing

Could you multiclass a 10 levels of land druid with 10 levels of moon druid, and, if so, would the level progression stack for wildshape and spells levels since they are all druid levels?

I am not currently in a campaign so I do not have a DM to ask.  I was reading the PHB and wondering about how the rules would handle this particular situation.  I am asking out of curiosity, and also because, from reading some forums, one complaint I saw was that druids did not multiclass well.  This seemed like it might be an interesting option that I had not seen anybody mention.  In fact, I had not seen anybody ever speak of multi-classing two sub-classes of the same kind in any class before.

Theoretically, one might wonder if one could do this with two types of monks or two types of warlock pacts, etc--although with the druid, it seems as if the payoff might be especially high.

That is why I asked.

Comment: Have you asked your DM if this is OK?  Have you read the section on Druids in the Players Handbook?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.se! Take a look at the [tour]; it's a useful introduction to the site. You appear to have accidentally created more than one account. You will be unable to manage your previous posts or benefit from the reputation they earn until you [merge your accounts using the instructions in the help centre](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: Regarding the edit: please see the link under “**This question already has an answer here:**” at the top of this post.